# Javascript/Jquery search array of pair-values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, find

I have a javascript array like this:

```
var ppts = [];
//...
ppts.push({x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y});
//...
var tmpArr = []; 
for (var i=1;ppts.length-1; i++) tmpArr.push(ppts[i].x);
alert(tmpArr[2]);
tmp_ctx.lineTo(parseInt(periodsPoints[i]/5+12), ( ($.inArray(parseInt(periodsPoints[i]/5+12),tmpArr) ) ? (ppts[i].y) : 0 );
```

For some unknown reason `alert(tmpArr[2]);` (or `alert(tmpArr)` ) do now show up. Though if I change it to

```
var tmpArr = []; 
for (var i=1;ppts.length-1; i++) { 
    tmpArr.push(ppts[i].x);
    alert(tmpArr[i]); 
    alert(tmpArr); 
}
```

It shows the `tmpArr` contents if inside the cycle. - why only inside it!?
I can not draw the line.

Is there a way I can search the `ppts` array for its x values?

Comment: first of all, that for loop condition is an always true..

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is wrong.

Try this:

`for (var i=1;i<=ppts.length-1; i++) tmpArr.push(ppts[i].x);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i missed that.